# ASP.NET this jquery script causing IE time out issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am just wondering if someone could explain what the following jQuery script does:

```
$j('.rc_bottom').each(function () {
    var boxDiv = $j(this).parent();
    if (boxDiv.outerWidth() > 0 && $j(this).css('width') != 'auto') {
        $j(this).css('width', $j('.content', boxDiv).outerWidth());
    }
});
```

And why it is causing an 8-sec longer page load than Firefox.

To note, I have a lot of `div`s with rc_bottom defined as follows.

```
<div class="clearfix mt_5">
    <div class="fl_left">
        <div class="rc_box-rc_blueBtn">
            <div class="buttonwidthbar">
                <div class="rc_blueBtn">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentPadding clearfix">
                            <div class="rc_top"></div>
                            <a href="<%# GetUrl((TrainingItem)Container.DataItem) %>"><span class="btnspan"><%# GetButtonText((TrainingItem)Container.DataItem)%></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rc_bottom" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many tags are on the page with `rc_bottom` as the class?  If there's only one on the page, then it will probably be related to the number of times you are using `$j(this)`.  If there are more, then you're probably experiencing the negative impact of the slower JavaScript engine in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize your code by reducing the number of dom elements fetched in your code.

```
var $this;
$j('.rc_bottom').each(function () {
        $this = $j(this);
        if ($this.parent().outerWidth() > 0 && $this.css('width') != 'auto') {
            $this.css('width', $this.prev().outerWidth());
        }
});
```

Note that inside the loop `$j('.content', boxDiv)` can be replaced by `$j(this).prev()` considering your markup which is faster than `$j('.content', boxDiv)`

Comment: Still takes 10 seconds or more to load in IE compare to nearly instant in Firefox

Comment: IE is always slower in JavaScript execution compared to other browsers. You might want to consider doing some stuff asynchronously after page loads.

Comment: Hey just noticed that when I change <div class="rc_bottom" style="width: 100%;" > to <div class="rc_bottom">, the page loads a lot quicker in IE and Jquery still resizes the width why would that happen ?

Comment: Because the condition `$this.css('width') != 'auto'` results to `true`.

Comment: But in both cases it is true tho ? And it both cases if goes inside the if loop thats what I dont understand

Comment: If `width` is empty i.e. not set then the condition is `true` and also if it is `100%` then also the condition is `true`.

Comment: Yup I get it both are set to true. But in IE if width isnt set the page loads in 2 seconds, both if width is set to 100% it takes 10 seconds. In both cases they get overwritten anyway. Does Jquery perhaps take a longer time to set a value than to overwrite ?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by class is not very fast in IE8 and older. `getElementByClassName` is new to the HTML5 spec and is only implimented in newer browsers.

Here is a JSPerf to show the performance hit IE8 and older takes when selecting by class: http://jsperf.com/jquery-getelementbyclassname-speed. You can see that on my computer, IE8 performed about 9% as fast as Chrome 17 when doing heavy class-based selections.

Also you can optimize your code a bit by using a `$.each()` or `for` (properly formatted) loop. Here is a JSPerf to show the performance difference between a few types of loops: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/7

Comment: Hey just noticed that when I change <div class="rc_bottom" style="width: 100%;" > to <div class="rc_bottom">, the page loads a lot quicker in IE and Jquery still resizes the width why would that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

If div with class `rc_bottom` has a parent with a specified `width` (greater than `0` and not `auto`) then the div with class `rc_bottom`s `width` is the same as it's sibling `.content` div.

**Bottom div is adjusted to content div when you want to show them (parent width).**

And like @ShankarSangoli said read control reference first time you need it and don't re-read it every time you want to use it.

Comment: Could you explain why you would want do this ? I mean resetting the bottom div width

Answer (score 0):

Stevie,

Try this code in IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rc_bottom').each(function() {
            var boxDiv = $(this).parent();
            if (boxDiv.outerWidth() > 0 && $(this).css('width') != 'auto') {
                $(this).css('width', $('.content', boxDiv).outerWidth());
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: So you suggest that running the code inside a `document.ready` event handler will be faster?

Comment: The code itself will not be faster but at least the page will load and then run the code.